# Problem 7.V Bartle Elements of Integration

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

$\textbf{Question:}$ Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be an arbitrary measure space. Let $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and satisfy for some $K>0$:

$$ \vert \varphi(t) \vert \leq K \vert t \vert, \forall t\in \mathbb{R} \tag{$*$}$$

If $f \in L^p$, then $\varphi \circ f$ belongs to $L^p$. Conversely, if $\varphi$ does not satisfy (*), there exists a measure space $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and a function $f \in L^p$ such that $\varphi \circ f$ does not belong to $L^p$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ If $\varphi$ satisfy $(*)$ we have for each $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and $x\in X$

$$ \vert (\varphi \circ f)(x) \vert = \vert \varphi(f(x)) \vert \leq K \vert f(x) \vert $$

$$ \implies \vert \varphi \circ f \vert^p \leq K^p \vert f \vert^p $$

So $\varphi \circ f \in L^p$. I can't solve the other statement, help please.

Comment: Yes, but I can't construct the measure space. I think that $X= \mathbb{R}$ and use the sequence $t_n$. This sequence not have subsequence convergent, but I can't construct the function.

Comment: In that answer, they just show that $\varphi \circ f \in L^p$ but the converse not.

Answer (score 3):

I think the result is not true as stated. In the inequality for $\phi$ we should add

> "for $|t|$ sufficiently large"

to make it correct.

First a counterexample: suppose the measure space is finite and $\phi (t)=\sqrt {|t|}$. Then the inequality fails but $\phi(f) \in L^{p}$ whenever $f \in L^{p}$.

---

Here is the proof when the question is modified as stated:

If (*) is false after the modification then there exist $t_n$ increasing t0 $\infty$ such that $\phi (t_n) >nt_n$. Consider the real line with Lebesgue measure and define $f(x)$ to be $t_n$ on $(t_n-r_n, t_n+r_n)$ where $r_n$'s are so small that the intervals $(t_n-r_n,t_n+r_n)$ are disjoint. Take $f$ to be $0$ outside these intervals.  Then $\int|f|^{p}=2\sum t_n^{p} r_n$ and $\int|\phi(f)|^{p}>2\sum n^{p}t_n^{p} r_n$. We only have to choose $r_n=\frac 1{n^{p}t_n^{p+1}}$.[ You can always choose $t_n$ to tend to $\infty$ as fast as you want so the disjointness condition can be met easily].

Comment: Nice!. In the part where rn's are so small that the intervals $(t_n −r_n,t_n + r_n)$ are disjoint, what do you mean exactly. Other question, $ \mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (t_n-r_n,t_n+r_n) $?

Comment: @n I forgot to say: take $f$ to be $0$ outside these intervals. Disjointness condition is $t_n+r_n <t_{n+1}-r_{n+1}$ so that the $n-$th interval is completely to the left of the next one.

Comment: Thanks, a last question. We have that $\varphi \circ f (x) = \varphi(0)$ in the points outside of the intervals $(t_n-r_n,t_n+r_n)$ right? So if calculate $\int \vert \varphi \circ f \vert^p = \int_{\cup (t_n - r_n, t_n+r_n)} \vert \varphi (t_n) \vert + \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \cup (t_n - r_n, t_n+r_n)} \vert \varphi(0) \vert$.  So $\int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \cup (t_n - r_n, t_n+r_n)} \vert \varphi(0) \vert= \infty$?.

Comment: @Norman we do not know whether $\phi (0)$ is $0$ or not. All you need for the proof is the fact that integral of $|\phi (f)|^{p}$ is **greater than or equal** to the sum of the integrals over those intervals.

Comment: Oh, so I consider : $\int \vert \varphi \circ f \vert^p \geq \int_{\cup (t_n-r_n,t_n+r_n)} \vert \varphi(t_n) \vert = \infty$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy:  Although the negation of condition (*) implies that the existence of $t_n$ such that $|\phi(t_n)|> n|t_n|$, it is not clear (at least to me) that the $t_n$ can be taken to be increasing (or as large as we want).

Comment: $(t_n)$ is surely unbounded. The other properties of $(t_n)$ can be obtained  by going to a subsequence. @OliverDiaz

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: one may  have $t_n=1/n^2 $ which would imply  $|\phi(t_n)|>\frac{1}{n}$. That does not seem to be in contradiction to the continuity of $\phi$, or the fact that $\phi(0)=0$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz The result is false as stated and I will edit may answer in  a few minutes. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: There is a problem with  your logic. @OliverDiaz

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: I don't this there is any problem. I just prove $p$ implies $q$ by proving that $\sim q$ implies $\sim p$, that is  $\sim(p\wedge (\sim q))\equiv(\sim p)\vee q\equiv\sim((\sim q)\wedge(\sim(\sim p))$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The counterexample does not work. What they ask you to prove is that if for any measure space $(X, \mathcal{F},\mu)$ we have $φ \circ f \in L^p$ for each $f \in L^p$ then $(*)$ is satisfied. The function you have given does not necessarily satisfy that requirement. Because it must be for any measure space, in your case you are only considering it as a finite measure.

Comment: The result is true as stated, I think. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that he Converse part is equivalent to the statement

**Theorem:** If $\phi\in C(\mathbb{R})$ and for any measure space $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$
$$\phi\circ f\in L_p(\mu)$$
whenever $f\in L_p(\mu)$, then $\phi$ satisfies (*).

We now prove this Theorem. We argue by contradiction. Suppose $\phi$ satisfies $\phi\circ f\in L_p(\mu)$ whenever $f\in L_p(\mu)$ for any measure space $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$, but that that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $t_n$ such that $|\phi(t_n)|> n|t_n|$.

In particular, consider the Lebesgue space $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B},\lambda_1)$. The function $h=\mathbb{1}_{[-1/2,1/2]}\in L_p$ and $\phi(h)=\phi(0)\mathbb{1}_{[-1/2,1/2]^c}+\phi(1)\mathbb{1}_{[-1/2,1/2]}$. By assumption, $\phi\circ h\in L_p$. Then
$$\|\phi\circ h\|^p_p=|\phi(1)|^p+|\phi(0)|^p\cdot\infty<\infty$$
and so,  $\phi(0)=0$. This shows that each $|t_n|>0$.

Fix $0<\varepsilon<p$ and define $a_n=\frac{1}{|t_n|^p  n^{1+\varepsilon}}$, and  let $\{A_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a sequence  of pairwise disjoint measurable sets in the real line such that $\lambda_1(A_n)=a_n$. Define
$$ f=\sum_nt_n\mathbb{1}_{A_n}$$
Clearly $\|f\|^p_p=\sum_n|t_n|^p\frac{1}{|t_n|^p n^{1+\varepsilon}}<\infty$; however
$$
\|\phi(f)\|_p=\sum_n|\phi(t_n)|^p\lambda_1(A_n)>\sum_nn^p|t_n|^p\frac{1}{|t_n|^pn^{1+\varepsilon}}=\infty$$
contraditing the assumption that $\phi\circ f\in L_p$ whenever $f\in L_p$. Therefore, there exist $k>0$ such that $|\phi(t)|\leq k|t|$ for all $t$.

---

Some remarks:

- The result also holds for $0<p<\infty$.
- If $\phi\in C(\mathbb{R})$ and $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ is an arbitrary but fixed nonatomic finite measure space, then the following slightly weaker result holds:
  $\phi\circ f\in L_p(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ whenever $f\in L_p(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ iff there is $k>0$ such that
  $$|\phi(t)|\leq k|t|\quad\text{for all}\quad|t|>k$$
  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3755045/121671

Comment: This is correct for the space you have chosen but the stated result is false for  a general measure space.  We are not at liberty to choose our space.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: what I proved is that if $\phi\in C(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies condition $\phi\circ f\in L_p$ whenever $f\in L_p$ for any measure space $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$, then there is $k>0$ such that $|\phi(t)|\leq k|t|$ for all $t$. This is equivalent to converse part of the OP.

Comment: That is not what the question is about. The space is fixed in advance and you are asked to prove equivalence  of the two conditions. You cannot choose your space.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: For the converse part, if there is no such space $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ (which is equivalent to saying that  $\phi\circ f\in L_p$ whenever $f\in L_p$ for any measure space $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$), then it must be that  $|\phi(t)|\leq k|t|$ for some $k>0$ and all $t$. (that is what I proved)

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: The statement "if $\phi$ does not satisfy ($*$) then there exists a measure space $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ and a function $f\in L_p(\mu)$ such that $\phi\circ f\notin L_p(\mu)$" is equivalent to the statement "if $\phi$ is such that for any measure space $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$, $\phi\circ f\in L_p(\mu)$ whenever $f\in L_p$, then $\phi$ satisfies $(*)$".

Answer (score 0):

The result **is true as stated**, differently from what the most upvoted answer's asserts.

$(\Rightarrow)$

$$\int|\phi\circ f|^p d\mu \leq K^p \int|f|^p d\mu< \infty$$

$(\Leftarrow)$ For every natural number there $\exists t_n$ such that $\phi(t_n)> n|t_n|$.

**Case I:** $t_n\not=0 \: ,\:\forall n$. We take $\mathbb{N}$ with the partition sigma algebra and also discrete measure $\mu(E)=\sum_{n\in E} \frac{1}{|t_n|^p n^2}$. Let $f(n)=|t_n|$. It is easilly seen that:

$$\int|\phi\circ f|^pd\mu=\sum_n|\phi\circ f(n)|^p\mu(n)\geq\sum_n n^p|t_n|^p \mu(n)\geq \sum_n\frac{1}{n}=\infty $$
$$\int |f|^pd\mu=\sum_n|t_n|^p\mu(n)=\sum_n\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}<\infty$$

**Case II:** $\exists t_n$ such that $t_n=0$. We take $\mathbb{N}$ with the partition sigma algebra and also the counting measure. $|\phi(0)|>0$. We take $f\equiv 0$.

$$\int|\phi\circ f|^p d\mu=\sum_n |\phi(0)|^p=\infty$$
$$\int|f|^p d\mu =0 <\infty$$